# two horizontal lines in header

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, rules

I need to reproduce the following header format:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}    
\pagestyle{fancy}
\cfoot{}
\lhead{\thepage}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `scrpage2` package (part of [`KOMA-Script`](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)) offers the `headtoprule` option.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[automark,headtopline,headsepline,nouppercase]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ihead{\headmark}% use \leftmark to display only chapters
\ohead{\pagemark}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\section{A section}

\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```

If you want this page style also to apply for chapter-starting pages, use the following preamble code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[automark,headtopline,headsepline,plainheadtopline,plainheadsepline,nouppercase]
    {scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ihead[\firstmark]{\headmark}
\ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
```

For the `report` class (or `book` with `oneside`), replace `\firstmark` with `\headmark`.

Finally, here's the preamble code for a header that doesn't switch between left and right pages in `twoside` mode:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[automark,headtopline,headsepline,nouppercase]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\lehead{\leftmark}
\lohead{\leftmark}
\rehead{\pagemark}
\rohead{\pagemark}
```

Comment: Thanks. How can we apply this format to all pages? without relocation

Comment: @Angel I'm not sure what you mean with "relocation" -- I hope my updated answer helps.

Comment: I wanna chapter name is on the left and page number is on the right.

Comment: @Angel That's unusual for `twoside` mode (`book`s default); answer updated again.

Answer (score 3):

Simply redefine `\headrule` (no information was provides for the headers on odd-numbered pages, so I used the same settings, but this is easily modifiable):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\small\sffamily\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\small\sffamily\thepage}
\renewcommand\headrule{\vskip-1.7\headheight\hrulefill\vskip2pt\hrulefill}
\setlength\headheight{13pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
\lipsum[1-7]

\end{document}
```

[image]

To apply the same header to all pages (as requested in a comment to other answer) redefine the plain style to be fancy:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\small\sffamily\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\small\sffamily\thepage}
\renewcommand\headrule{\vskip-1.7\headheight\hrulefill\vskip2pt\hrulefill}
\setlength\headheight{13pt}
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
\lipsum[1-7]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can get the lower line from the default value of `\headrulewidth`, which is `0.4pt`. As for the upper line, insert your own `\hrule`:

```
\lhead{\hrule\vspace{2pt}\thepage}
```

The `\vspace` is there to prevent the `\hrule` being too close to the page number; you can adjust the value to your liking.

The layout for the image is

```
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markleft{\MakeLowercase{\chaptername\ \thechapter. #1}}}
\lhead{\hrule\vspace{2pt}\sffamily\chaptermark}
\rhead{\thepage}
```

Comment: The second code is not correct.